# Google App Engine development server random (?) slowdowns

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm doing a small web application which might need to eventually scale somewhat, and am curious about Google App Engine.  However, I am experiencing a problem with the development server (dev_appserver.py):

At seemingly random, requests will take 20-30 seconds to complete, even if there is no hard computation or data usage.  One request might be really quick, even after changing a script of static file, but the next might be very slow.  It seems to occur more systematically if the box has been left for a while without activity, but not always.

CPU and disk access is low during the period. There is not allot of data in my application either.

Does anyone know what could cause such random slowdowns? I've Google'd and searched here, but need some pointers.. /:  I've also tried --clear_datastore and --use_sqlite, but the latter gives an error: *DatabaseError('file is encrypted or is not a database',)*.  Looking for the file, it does not seem to exist.

I am on Windows 8, python 2.7 and the most recent version of the App Engine SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it. It (IIRC) keeps the whole DB (datastore) in memory using a "emulation" of the real thing. There are lots of other issues that you won't see when deployed.

I'd suggest that your **hard drive is spinning down and the delay you see is it taking a few seconds to wake back up.**

If this becomes a problem, develop using the deployed version. It's not so different.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen in all web browsers? I had issues like this when viewing a local app engine dev site in several browsers at the same time for cross-browser testing. IE would then struggle, with requests taking about as long as you describe.

If this is the issue, I found the problems didn't occur with IETester.

Sorry if it's not related, but I thought this was worth mentioning just in case.